# how to use google place api when query contained space?

Tags: php, google-places-api

recently, i try to use google place api to search place. at first, it worked well. then i found that when i passed query which contained spaces. the response always is bad request. however, when I put the query into browser directly, it runs well. Here is my code, can anyone help me out?

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=$name&location=$lat,$lng&radius=$raidus&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=mykey";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

for example, if $name is 'restaurant', it works. but if $name is 'restaurant food', it said bad request. however, I put url into browser, it works again. I try to sanitize the query parameter, but the response still said the bad request. I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Always when passing URL somewhere, you should encode it. That will replace for example spaces with %20 etc. So your $name would be = restaurant%20food

Don't worry about google, it will decode it automatically.

Either you can encdode it manually or you can use function like this:

```
$query = urlencode($query);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: if he did the whole $url above it would fail, it would encode the url he is posting to not just the query string at issue

Comment: +1 for @Dagon. Encoding the whole `$url` variable as you've indicated would cause the request to fail.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to encode the URL parameters using PHP's `urlencode()`:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=". urlencode($name) ."&location=$lat,$lng&radius=$raidus&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=mykey";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```